# How can I read more than one column in this

Tags: mysql

In 1_products t2 I have other columns called make,model

When I add them

```
(SELECT 
            t2.code,t2.make,t2.model
        FROM .....
```

I get

> Error 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT 
    t1.fk_products_id,
    (SELECT 
            t2.code
        FROM
            1_products t2
        WHERE
            t2.id = t1.fk_products_id
        order by code
        limit 1)
FROM
    1_stock t1
WHERE
    t1.branch = 1 and t1.dispatch <> 0;
```

Comment: So the question should be whether you're going the right way about getting data out or not, that subquery there makes no sense then, does it? You should describe what you want, not the error during the attempts to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return more than one column in an inline query.  If you want to return more than one column for each `t1.fk_products_id` then you will have to rewrite the query similar to this:

```
SELECT t1.fk_products_id,
  t2.code,
  t2.make,
  t2.model
FROM 1_stock t1
LEFT JOIN 1_products t2
  on t1.fk_products_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.branch = 1 
  and t1.dispatch <> 0;
```